# How does a switch know out of which port to send a frame?

Tags: arp, ping

When a ping passes a switch, how does the switch know which port to send it to?

Answer (score -4):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, in that case i apologize in advance.
But packets contain in their header many fields, one of which is the destination port. So the switch simply reads that information.

Comment: This is a basic network. I got a question is PC1 ping to PC2.
Internal process how it work.

Comment: Packets DO NOT contain a destination SWITCH port in their header. There is such a thing as a destination port in TCP/UDP, but it has no relationship to switch ports.